# How to transform process output using streams

Tags: node.js, child-process, node-streams

I'm trying to pipe the output from `execSync` into a `Transform` stream with the goal of **adding a prefix to every line.**

Below is an example of the Transform stream which works as expected but data is written manually.

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const { Transform, Writable } = require('node:stream');

const addPrefixStream = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    callback(
      null,
      chunk
        .toString()
        .split('\n')
        .map(l => `custom prefix: ${l}`)
        .join('\n')
    );
  },
});

addPrefixStream.pipe(process.stdout);
addPrefixStream.write('some multiple\nline output');

console.log(addPrefixStream instanceof Writable);
```

The console log at the end prints `true`.

Here is an example of piping the output of a process into a file which also works as expected.

```
const { createWriteStream } = require('fs');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const { Writable } = require('node:stream');

const outStream = createWriteStream('./out');
outStream.on('open', () => {
  execSync('ls -lh ./', { stdio: ['ignore', outStream, 'ignore'] });
});

console.log(outStream instanceof Writable);
```

The console at the end also prints `true`.

Finally, here is my attempt at combining the previous examples to pipe the output of a process into the `Transform` stream and onto stdout.

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const { Transform } = require('node:stream');

const addPrefixStream = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    callback(
      null,
      chunk
        .toString()
        .split('\n')
        .map(l => `custom prefix: ${l}`)
        .join('\n')
    );
  },
});

addPrefixStream.pipe(process.stdout);
execSync('ls -lh ./', { stdio: ['ignore', addPrefixStream, 'ignore'] });
```

This unfortunately throws the following error
`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'stdio' is invalid. Received Transform {`

I've tried to connect both `Writable` and `Readable` streams to the stdio parameter but to no avail.

The only type of stream that I have managed to successfully get working is the Writable stream produced by createWriteStream but this bypasses any form of modification and goes directly into a file. Both of which, in my case, are undesirable.